# Make sf::Shape a parameter type, SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make a function that take in parameter a sf::Shape object ( **in order to accept only cirlce, rectangles etc** )
But as it is an abstract class, it throws me that error "parameter of abstract class type sf::Shape is not allowed"

This is the signature of my function :
`GraphObject::GraphObject(sf::Shape shape, int z = 0)`

Is there another way to pass shapes as parameter ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept `shape` as a reference or a pointer:
`GraphObject::GraphObject(sf::Shape& shape, int z = 0)` or `GraphObject::GraphObject(sf::Shape* shape, int z = 0)`.

The reasoning is pretty self-explanatory. You cannot have objects of an abstract class type - well because they are [abstract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class).